# Excel: Counting similarities between two lists

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create a bracket that automatically scores itself based on a key. Given a list of teams, I want to compare it to the key's list, and count the number of consistent values. For example, I would like to compare the following two lists and obtain the value 3 (FLA, GONZ, PITT are in both lists):

```
   +-------+------+
   |   A   |  B   |
   +-------+------+
1  | FLA   | FLA  |
   +-------+------+
2  | DUKE  | UNC  |
   +-------+------+
3  | WISC  | MICH |
   +-------+------+
4  | GONZ  | GONZ |
   +-------+------+
5  | OHIO  | CONN |
   +-------+------+
6  | PITT  | PITT |
   +-------+------+
```

I've been attempting to use the COUNTIF() function -- perhaps `=COUNTIF(A1:A6,B1:B6)`, but this only compares the entirety of the two lists rather than the individual values.  The lists are also quite long, so I would like to avoid comparing the lists using a sequence of COUNTIF() statements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I entered the following in D1 and used `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` to enter it (instead of just `Enter`, as it's an array formula).

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A6=B1:B6,1,0))
```